# how to change font color in a column when I hover over anywhere on a section in wordpress?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages, elementor

I made a transparent menu with white text on it and when we hover it the whole topbar becomes white and the text becomes invisible because of the same color.

I want to change the font colors to black of all the items in the columns when we hover anywhere on the top bar.

I am using elementor.

This is my website:
http://ha123.epizy.com

Please suggest if there is a plugin for this or any code. As a newbie I would be really happy to learn from you guys.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could solve this using custom CSS code. If you use Elementor Pro, you could put this CSS inside of the plugin somewhere, but if not you can just add it either in the Customizer in Wordpress, or in a custom (child) theme.

Something like this could work in your case:

```
.elementor-widget-ekit-nav-menu:hover .elementskit-navbar-nav > li > a {
  color: black;
}
```

*You might actually also be able to solve this using Elementor itself in the style settings somewhere, but that depends on how everything is set up and which elements you are using.*